# office 365 outlook account not receiving emails from SPD workflow Send an Email action

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow, office-365

I have made a simple workflow for Office 365 to send an email to the person who created an item in the list.

But **it's not sending the email to the office 365 users, instead i provide static others email(not office 365) it's working perfectly.**

Here is the workflow snapshot to send email

[image]

is there any additional settings need to be configured for allow emails in office 365 outlook account?

Thanks

Comment: Is this in an app using VS or SPD??

Comment: Log the email of the current user, see if you can find a clue.

Comment: stephen - this is spd workflow...

Aveenav - i also getting correct email of current user into history list

Comment: even i am facing same issue